# How to get a instance variable name from this instance in Java

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a way to do something like this?

```java
public class T {
    String var = "Some value";

    public void show() {
        System.out.println(var.getClass().getName()); // Prints var
    }
}
```

---

### Edit

Use case: I have a class `X`with many instance variables that will be passed as arguments to another class `Y` main entry point. The `X` class has this method:

```java
protected String[] getAttributesAsCommandLineArguments() {
    return new String[] {
        String.format("--%s=%s", "state", state),
        String.format("--%s=%s", "accountId", accountId),
        String.format("--%s=%s", "pageId", pageId),
        String.format("--%s=%s", "retroactiveDays", retroactiveDays),
        String.format("--%s=%s", "state", state),
        String.format("--%s=%s", "task", task),
        String.format("--%s=%s", "channel", channel),
    };
  }
```

I dont want to repeat both quoted string name for each `String.format()` line.

I want something like this:

```java
protected String[] getAttributesAsCommandLineArguments() {
    return new String[] {
        String.format("--%s=%s", state.getDeclaredName(), state),
        String.format("--%s=%s", accountId.getDeclaredName(), accountId),
        String.format("--%s=%s", pageId.getDeclaredName(), pageId),
        String.format("--%s=%s", retroactiveDays.getDeclaredName(), retroactiveDays),
        String.format("--%s=%s", state.getDeclaredName(), state),
        String.format("--%s=%s", task.getDeclaredName(), task),
        String.format("--%s=%s", channel.getDeclaredName(), channel),
    };
  }
```

Comment: What is the output you expect from that println statement? The name of the variable? Can you explain the use case?

Comment: I think that the given example is self explained, but ok. Imagine that I have an instance variable like `var` in the above example called `awesomeInstanceVariable`, I want to get a string containing the name of this `awesomeInstanceVariable` variable which is "awesomeInstanceVariable"

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. "Use case" means - what do you need to get the name of the variable for. What kind of project needs to know the name of a variable in a class? If we know, we may be able to provide a solution better than just `println("var")`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Question updated

Comment: OK, I see. Well, you can't use the field name as an identifier for this. You can use reflection, and maybe use annotations to mark only the fields that interest you. I don't see the benefit in not using literal strings, though.

Comment: **THATS IS IT!!!** This is exactly what I want!. This class is a subclass and I have other instance variables in the other subclasses. I need to code this method each time I create a new subclass. Annotations will save my life if that can be done!